# How can we fix this AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'map'?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, transfer-learning

I'm trying to run this code on an AWS EMR instance to get features from images by Transfer learning model but I get this error code : AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'map'
*
input = np.stack(content_series.map(preprocess))
preds = model.predict(input)

here is the whole code :

```
def preprocess(content):
    
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(content)).resize([224, 224])
    arr = img_to_array(img)
    return preprocess_input(arr)

def featurize_series(model, content_series):
    """
    Featurize a pd.Series of raw images using the input model.
    :return: a pd.Series of image features
    """
    input = np.stack(content_series.map(preprocess))
    preds = model.predict(input)
    output = [p.flatten() for p in preds]
    return pd.Series(output)

@pandas_udf('array<float>', PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER)
def featurize_udf(content_series_iter):
    '''
    This method is a Scalar Iterator pandas UDF wrapping our featurization function.
    The decorator specifies that this returns a Spark DataFrame column of type ArrayType(FloatType).

    :param content_series_iter: This argument is an iterator over batches of data, where each batch
                              is a pandas Series of image data.
    '''
    # With Scalar Iterator pandas UDFs, we can load the model once and then re-use it
    # for multiple data batches.  This amortizes the overhead of loading big models.
    model = model_fn()
    for content_series in content_series_iter:
        yield featurize_series(model, content_series)
```

do u have any suggestions ? tks

I tried to change instance config

Comment: `map(preprocess, content_series)`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the content_series.map method is trying to apply the preprocess function to each element of content_series, which is assumed to be a pandas Series. However, the error message indicates that content_series is a 'bytes' object, which does not have a 'map' attribute.

It appears that the content_series_iter input to the featurize_udf function is an iterator over batches of image data, where each batch is a pandas Series of image data. To resolve the error, you'll need to modify the featurize_udf function to convert the 'bytes' objects in each batch to pandas Series before applying the preprocess function:

```
@pandas_udf('array<float>', PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER)
def featurize_udf(content_series_iter):
    model = model_fn()
    for content_series in content_series_iter:
        content_series = pd.Series(content_series.tolist())
        yield featurize_series(model, content_series)
```

This should resolve the AttributeError and allow you to run the code successfully on the AWS EMR instance.